# Seeking module/technique for giving site visitors a download "gift" in exchage for their email

Tags: 7

A friend has an eBook site where he sells his eBook. A customer bought a large bulk order for use as a large group gift, but he wants my friend's site to be able to collect the email addresses of all the people who goto the eBook site and retrieve their gifted eBook.

So, we're seeking some module or technique that an anonymous user can visit a page, and by supplying their email to a form, they get access to download their pre-purchased eBook.

Now, I know how to write a module to do this, but my friend can't afford me, I'm already working full time, an so on... anyone know of some technique or module to accomplish this without writing a new module?

Seems like something along the lines of a CCK form for getting each email, which would then need to be verified by something like the Email Verification module, and once passing that test the user simply gets a role assignment for access to the download page.

However, being a code-monkey, I have no idea how to handle the glue logic of this solution without writing a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Webform Rules Module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules). On submit and validation of an email address have a Rule that redirects the user to a download page. Of course, since it's Rules you might be able to conjure up all kinds of wonderful complicated things. I also found [these lovely tutorials](http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-rules-with-nodeone-part-1-overview) on Rules at NodeOne. However, you might be able to write a module faster than it would take to work through all those videos.

Comment: Thanks Adam. My friend has his own developer, and this sounds perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [FileField Track](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_track) module.

> A simple module that tracks downloads of files added through CCK/Fields by asking anonymous users to enter their email address. Returning anonymous users are tracked using a cookie. A tracking interface shows email address and user account information for tracked files downloaded on the site.

The latest stable release (7.x-1.4), covered by security coverage advisory policy, has been release on October 1, 2012. The module isn't anymore maintained from the original maintainer, and it's marked as *Seeking new maintainer*.